# Create Time series with MySQL data in R Shiny

Tags: r, time-series, shiny, rmysql

I'm trying to develop a dashboard using R Shiny which extract data from a MySQL database and represents it in graphical form. I need to create a time series using several data. But a problem occurs when the time stamp values in MySQL cannot be converted in to date time values in the time series. Following is my `server.R` code:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="root",password="891208",host="localhost",dbname="openPos")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 query1 <- reactive({ "SELECT sale_time,sum(quantity_purchased * item_unit_price) 
                            AS revenue, sum(quantity_purchased * item_cost_price) AS cost,
                            sum(quantity_purchased * item_unit_price)-sum(quantity_purchased * item_cost_price) as profit
                            FROM ospos_sales, ospos_sales_items
                            WHERE ospos_sales.sale_id = ospos_sales_items.sale_id
                            GROUP BY sale_time"})
result1 <- reactive({dbGetQuery(con,query1())})
z <- reactive({ts(result1())})
output$ts <- renderPlot({p<-ts.plot(z())
                       print(p)})
output$table <-renderTable({z()})
```

The output of the table will look like this

Can anyone please tell me why I can't create a time series with these database values?

Comment: Can you, in an unreactive simulation, tell us what the output of `dbGetQuery(con, query1)` looks like - I'd expect it to be a data.frame, and putting it straight into `ts` as an argument isn't going to work, as `ts` needs its input to be of a different form.

Comment: Gavin you're right. It's a data.frame, but the time stamp values view as characters. So can you tell me how can I convert my query result in to ts?

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamps are guaranteed to be at regular intervals, then you should be fine with something along the lines of `ts(result1()[-1], start=myStart, frequency=myFrequency)` where I'm removing the first column as you won't want to plot time against time - the other columns will then be plotted as a time series starting from myStart (which you should be able to extract from the `result1()[1,1]` (we have no idea what format of timestamp you have, so it's hard to give guidance), and `myFrequency` will be the number of measurements you make per unit of time.

If you don't have regular timepoints, then `ts` is entirely the wrong thing to use - most people seem to use the `zoo` package in this case.

Comment: So If I want my time series to be based on day "%Y-%m-%d", how can I get that in ts?

Comment: Realistically, you can't, unless you have exactly the same number of measurements per day.  What elements of the `ts` class do you need that it's so important to cast it as a time-series object.  If it's just plotting, then just use native R plots.  If you're wanting to do some modelling along the lines of arima, then you should know you need regular-spaced measurements before even contemplating this.